# Proof by contradiction that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, why assume the fraction is simplified?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

As a student with no history of proof-based math courses, I am having some difficulty understanding the proof by contradiction by assuming $\sqrt{2} = a/b$ and that a and b are in least common denominators.

Could you explain how this disproves that it is irrational? Doesn't it just merely disprove that our initial assumption that a and b are even, is wrong?

I'm speaking of the popular proof that is given here:https://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html

Comment: Please include the *precise* proof you have in mind (there are *many* variants). Also please state precisely where in the proof you are having difficulty.

Comment: Ok I put in a link

Comment: There is no assumption that $a,b$ are even. It is proven that they are even, contradicting the assumption that they are relatively prime.

Comment: So how does that prove that sqrt(2) is irrational?

Comment: Another way to conclude is that $\sqrt 2 = (p/2)/(q/2),\,$ contra $q$ is the least denominator. Here you don't need to assume $\,p,q\,$ coprime at the start.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/812443/589.

Comment: If the initial assumption is wrong, how can there exist some $a,b$?

Comment: @SimpleArt Can't there exist some a,b not in their least common denominator form

Comment: Then there exists $c,d$ in reduced form where $\frac ab=\frac cd$

Comment: @Goldname Any fraction can be simplified to be in lowest terms, so if there cannot be a fraction in lowest terms equal to $\sqrt{2}$ there cannot be any fraction at all.

Comment: I see, that makes sense